In mixed-effects model, can a variable be both a grouping factor in a random intercept and a fixed effect?
I've come across several discussions on mixed-effects models, yet none seem to address my specific query. From what I've gathered, it appears that the model specification below is correct, allowing a variable to function as both a covariate in a random slope and a fixed effect:
y ~ x, random = ~ x | g # this is correct

However, I'm uncertain about the validity of the following model, where a variable serves as both a grouping factor in a random intercept and a fixed effect:
y ~ x + g3, random = ~ x | g3/g2/g1 # is this correct (A)
y ~ g3, random = ~ x | g3/g2/g1 # is this correct (B)

If the above model specification is incorrect and it is necessary to keep g3 as a fixed effect, would the below specification be correct?
y ~ x + g3, random = ~ x | g3:g2/g1 # should this be preferred over (A)
y ~ g3, random = ~ x | g3:g2/g1 # should this be preferred over (B)

Could someone kindly provide clarification on this matter? Thank you in advance for your assistance!

This is not a great answer, but summarizes what I've personally learned so far and offers some sources:

If your predictor is categorical (using dummies), the answer is no. A categorical predictor uses the same variance as a random effect grouping factor, so you'd essentially be modeling the same term twice.

If your predictor is continuous, the answer is no because a continuous variable can't be used as a random effect grouping variable.
However, I have sometimes seen it done that a predictor with several discrete levels (often a time variable, e.g. 1 to 5) is specified as a continuous fixed effect and a random effect grouping factor. This seems to produce reasonable models that converge etc., but I'm not sure what this does to parameter estimates.

So basically, no. BUT Thierry Onkelinx presents 2 exceptions here: https://www.muscardinus.be/statistics/fixed-and-random-effect.html Ben Bolker refers to this document in his GLMM FAQ: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html
3-a) If your intended random effect is "implicitly nested" within your intended fixed effect. This may apply to your middle models. If g2 and g1 are implicitly nested within g3, then that may be OK. I'm not entirely sure what implicitly nested means, though.
3-b) if the intended "fixed-and-random" variable is entered as a discrete variable (see the first link). I think this may actually be the same thing as the "time as continuous fixed effect and random effect grouping variable" from #2.



What you are usually after is the notion of an "overall" parameter, and the changes driven by the groups/hierarchies in that overall parameter.
For "base level" intercepts, it usually means having an intercept $\alpha$ and a group level intercept $\alpha_{[i]}$ that would represent the change to that overall mean attributed to the group $i$.
So, what is random and what is fixed? By formulating as y ~ x + g, random = ~ x | g
(simplified from your example) I'm guessing we are writing the model:
$$
y = \alpha_i + \beta x +  \beta_{[i]}x
$$
Which for me, it makes sense, we have a fixed effect per each group of g and we are trying to gage how the effect of $x$ on y varies per each group of g.

Thank you for providing the insight, Guilherme Marthe!

Guilherme Marthe, could you cite any references supporting this?

My goto source when studying is Gelman's "Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models". Ben Bolker's awesome FAQ, mentioned in the other answer is also great. Do check out the 'Model Specification' section, specifically the lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy) call where he presents the equatiomatic package. It has a similar structure to what you present, I think.
